# Is it possible to change your MyOpenID.com username?

Tags: openid, username

I have been poking around for a while and can't seem to find anywhere to do it or if it is even possible so..

**Is it possible to change your MyOpenID.com username?**

Comment: If you use Google as your OpenID, does this change it? http://www.google.com/profiles/me/editprofile?edit=r I am not sure, but it might.

Comment: It is worth noting that with the new changes to stack exchange this is now very easy to do by visiting your own profile and clicking edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for an **answer** to the question:

You can modify your display name without changing your openID login for most websites (like stackexchange, stackoverflow, superuser) by going to your profile and clicking on the edit button.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the provider if they will let you change your username or not.

However, When you add your OpenID to a webapp, it will usually store the username + provider fx `username.myopenid.com`. So if you do change your username, you will most likely have to revalidate / add it to your accounts on the webapps you use.

Comment: Now would revalidating cause loss of reputation etc. Because then it's not so much a rename but may as well just make a new account.